# scrapy: convert html string to HtmlResponse object

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I have a raw html string that I want to convert to scrapy HTML response object so that I can use the selectors `css` and `xpath`, similar to scrapy's `response`. How can I do it?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

First of all, if it is for debugging or testing purposes, you can use the [`Scrapy shell`](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/shell.html):

```
$ cat index.html
<div id="test">
    Test text
</div>

$ scrapy shell index.html
>>> response.xpath('//div[@id="test"]/text()').extract()[0].strip()
u'Test text'
```

There are [different objects available in the shell](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/shell.html#available-scrapy-objects) during the session, like `response` and `request`.

---

Or, you can instantiate an [`HtmlResponse` class](https://scrapy.readthedocs.org/en/latest/topics/request-response.html#htmlresponse-objects) and provide the HTML string in `body`:

```
>>> from scrapy.http import HtmlResponse
>>> response = HtmlResponse(url="my HTML string", body='<div id="test">Test text</div>', encoding='utf-8')
>>> response.xpath('//div[@id="test"]/text()').extract()[0].strip()
u'Test text'
```

Comment: thanks alecxe, I am using Selenium becuase of some ajaxiness. I want to convert driver.page_source into the same object as resposne so that I can reuse some extractors (using css and xpath selectors) instead of having to resort to lxml. I think your second option is the one I need.

Comment: @yayu then, you probably don't need to create an HTML Response, but, rather a `Selector`, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18836286/scraping-with-scrapy-and-selenium and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17975471/selenium-with-scrapy-for-dynamic-page. Might help. Thanks.

Comment: @yayu and, as a side note, there can be a point there you would have much more selenium than scrapy in the project - at this point, think about whether there is any point in scrapy at all.

Comment: @yayu also [`scrapyjs`](https://github.com/scrapinghub/scrapyjs) might be worth trying - may be you could avoid using `selenium`.

Comment: @alecxe is there any way to set the meta attribute for this `response` object. I know `response meta` is an alias for the `request meta` object. But since there is no `request` associated with this `response`, is there any workaround?

Comment: as of today, HtmlResponse object requires another argument, encoding. You can do it like: HtmlResponse(url='http://scrapy.org', body=u'some body', encoding='utf-8')

Comment: On linux, `scrapy shell index.html` does not work and it's well documented in here https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/shell.html#launch-the-shell. Use `scrapy shell ./index.html` instead.

Answer (score 18):

[alecxe](https://stackoverflow.com/users/771848/alecxe)'s answer is right, but this is the correct way to instantiate a `Selector` from `text` in [scrapy](https://scrapy.org):

```
>>> from scrapy.selector import Selector
>>> body = '<html><body><span>good</span></body></html>'
>>> Selector(text=body).xpath('//span/text()').get()

'good'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can import native scrapy selector `Selector` and declare the html string as the text arg to be parsed.

```
from scrapy.selector import Selector


def get_list_text_from_html_string(html_string):
    html_item = Selector(text=html_string)
    elements = [_li.get() for _li in html_item.css('ul > li::text')]
    return elements

list_html_string = '<ul class="teams">\n<li>Bayern M.</li>\n<li>Palmeiras</li>\n<li>Liverpool</li>\n<li>Flamengo</li></ul>'
print(get_list_text_from_html_string(list_html_string))
>>> ['Bayern M.', 'Tigres', 'Liverpool', 'Flamengo']
```