# Using Scrapy to simulate AJAX requests to collect paginated data

Tags: python, python-3.x, scrapy, data-science

I am doing a mini-project to collect some data from a popular League of Legends website, www.op.gg. For example, if you go to [this](https://na.op.gg/summoner/userName=C9+Zven) page, you will see that there are 10 games worth of data shown on the right. If you keep scrolling down, you will see ["Show More"](https://prnt.sc/r9ddqx) at the bottom which will show the next 20 results, and so on. When I inspect the "Show More" element using chrome tools, I see the following entry:

```
<a href="#" onclick="$.OP.GG.matches.list.loadMore($(this)); return false;" class="Button">Show More</a>
```

I am currently using Scrapy to grab several datapoints from pages like this, and I have been successful in grabbing the first 10 games that show up but need some help on how to keep grabbing more until a set time period (i.e. keep showing more results until the "data-datetime" element in each GameItemWrap class is 30 days ago from runtime.)

My code is below:

```
import scrapy

class PostsSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "posts"
    start_urls = [
        'https://na.op.gg/summoner/userName=C9+Zven',
        'https://na.op.gg/summoner/userName=From+Iron'
    ]

    def parse(self, response):
        summoner_name = response.css('.SummonerLayout>.Header>.Profile>.Information>.Name::text').get()
        rank_type = response.css('.TierRankInfo .RankType::text').get()
        tier_rank = response.css('.TierRankInfo .TierRank::text').get()   

        game_lists = []
        dict_per_game = {}

        for game in response.css('div.GameItemWrap'):
            dict_per_game['summoner_id'] = game.css('.GameItem::attr(data-summoner-id)').get() 
            dict_per_game['data_game_time'] = game.css('.GameItem::attr(data-game-time)').get() 
            dict_per_game['game_type'] = str.strip(game.css('.Content .GameStats .GameType::text').get())
            dict_per_game['date_time_epoch'] = game.css('.Content .GameStats .TimeStamp ._timeago::attr(data-datetime)').get()
            dict_per_game['game_result'] = str.strip(game.css('.Content .GameStats .GameResult::text').get())
            dict_per_game['champ_name'] = game.css('.Content .GameSettingInfo .ChampionName a::text').get()
            dict_per_game['kill'] = game.css('.Content .KDA .KDA .Kill::text').get()
            dict_per_game['death'] = game.css('.Content .KDA .KDA .Death::text').get()
            dict_per_game['assist'] = game.css('.Content .KDA .KDA .Assist::text').get()
            game_lists.append(dict_per_game)
            dict_per_game = {}

        yield {
            'summoner_name': summoner_name,
            'rank_type': rank_type, 
            'tier_rank': tier_rank, 
            'games': game_lists
        }

        # This is where I would like to add some code to retrieve more results for this profile going back to 30 days ago from runtime
```

Comment: using only `Selenium` you could simply click button. Using other tools you could check in DevTools (in tab Network) what request it send when you click button (especiall XHR requests) and use it - maybe it will work without simulate AJAX and you could get JSON data which can be easily converted to Python's list/dictionary. To simulate AJAX you would have to add one header `XMLHttpRequest`

Comment: When I use the network tab and click on 'Show More', [this](https://na.op.gg/summoner/matches/ajax/averageAndList/startInfo=1582695495&summonerId=91419120) kind of link appears. It is a JSON of HTML strings-- any idea the most efficient way to parse this in the same way I can do CSS parsing from Scrapy?

Comment: you can use `lxml` or `Beautifulsoup` to parse it and search usign `css` or `xpath`. Or you can use Scrapy and `HtmlResponse` or `Selector` to create response from string/HTML - see [scrapy: convert html string to HtmlResponse object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27323740/scrapy-convert-html-string-to-htmlresponse-object)

Comment: The HTML field from [this](https://na.op.gg/summoner/matches/ajax/averageAndList/startInfo=1582695495&summonerId=91419120) JSON is broken or partial HTML so I am not sure what the best approach here is in parsing this HTML string efficiently. For example, if you dump the HTML string into a file and save it as an HTML file, opening it up will show something that doesn't make sense. Is there any way I can still search this string using CSS selectors?

Comment: did you try to use this HTML directly with `HtmlResponse`, `Selector`, `BeautifulSoup` or `lmxl`  - they don't need full HTML to work.

Comment: from scrapy import Selector

data = Selector(text=string)
data.css('#myid::text').get()