# Scraping ajax pages which return javascript files that generate html nodes

Tags: python, web-scraping

Some pages do not return raw data (like json or xml or html) on ajax. Instead they use some framework like dojo where ajax calls return js files which somehow populate the html nodes.

I am wondering if there is a non Selenium strategy to scrapy data from these pages.

Comment: as far as i know you need a browser. if you do not want selenium try phantomjs or similar. Have you tried http://jeanphix.me/Ghost.py/?

Comment: @gosom Phantomjs is pretty cool and works well in my current implementation locally. the downside is that it is very slow. I also had problems deploying the code to heroku, so I'm wondering if there's something better.

Comment: maybe try that: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/528293/Scraping-JavaScript-webpages-with-Webkit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alternatively to the `selenium` or `webkit` based approach, you can parse the javascript with a javascript code parser, like [`slimit`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/slimit). It definitely raises the complexity and reliability of the web-scraping since you go down to a bare hardcore metal with it - think about it as a "white box" approach as opposed to `selenium` based high-level "black box" one.

Here's the answer I've given for an exact same topic/problem you are asking about:

- [Having trouble accessing xpath attribute with scrapy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27426768/having-trouble-accessing-xpath-attribute-with-scrapy/27428141#27428141)

It involves the use of `slimit` to grab an object from the javascript code, loading it to a python data structure via `json` module and parsing the HTML inside with `BeautifulSoup` parser.